# How to receive Map data value of an array from firestore inside Dropdownlist

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get all the name from array in Firestore as Dropdownlist.But I can't be able to get all the data in Dropdownlist. Can someone help me out to solve this problem? Thanks.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                        .collection('location')
                                        .snapshots(),
                                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                                        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                                      if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
                                      if (setDefault) {
                Storagelocation = snapshot.data.docs[0]['Location'][0]['name'];
                debugPrint('setDefault: $Storagelocation');
              }

                                      return DropdownButton(
                                        isExpanded: false,
                                        value: Storagelocation,
                                        items: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                                            value: document['Location'][index]['name'],
                                            child: Text('${document['Location'][index]['name']}'),
                                          );
                                        }).toList(),
                                        onChanged: (data) {
                                          setState(
                                                () {
                                              Storagelocation =data;
                                            },
                                          );
                                        },
                                      );
                                    },
                                  );
```

[Firebase collection Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zj7v.png)

Answer (score 1):

Complete example:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Initialize Firebase
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var carMake, carMakeModel;
  var setDefaultMake = true, setDefaultMakeModel = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint('carMake: $carMake');
    debugPrint('carMakeModel: $carMakeModel');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Center(
              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('carMake')
                    .orderBy('name')
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  // Safety check to ensure that snapshot contains data
                  // without this safety check, StreamBuilder dirty state warnings will be thrown
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
                  // Set this value for default,
                  // setDefault will change if an item was selected
                  // First item from the List will be displayed
                  if (setDefaultMake) {
                    carMake = snapshot.data.docs[0].get('name');
                    debugPrint('setDefault make: $carMake');
                  }
                  return DropdownButton(
                    isExpanded: false,
                    value: carMake,
                    items: snapshot.data.docs.map((value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: value.get('name'),
                        child: Text('${value.get('name')}'),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      debugPrint('selected onchange: $value');
                      setState(
                        () {
                          debugPrint('make selected: $value');
                          // Selected value will be stored
                          carMake = value;
                          // Default dropdown value won't be displayed anymore
                          setDefaultMake = false;
                          // Set makeModel to true to display first car from list
                          setDefaultMakeModel = true;
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Center(
              child: carMake != null
                  ? StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('cars')
                          .where('make', isEqualTo: carMake)
                          .orderBy("makeModel").snapshots(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                          debugPrint('snapshot status: ${snapshot.error}');
                          return Container(
                            child:
                            Text(
                                'snapshot empty carMake: $carMake makeModel: $carMakeModel'),
                          );
                        }
                        if (setDefaultMakeModel) {
                          carMakeModel = snapshot.data.docs[0].get('makeModel');
                          debugPrint('setDefault makeModel: $carMakeModel');
                        }
                        return DropdownButton(
                          isExpanded: false,
                          value: carMakeModel,
                          items: snapshot.data.docs.map((value) {
                            debugPrint('makeModel: ${value.get('makeModel')}');
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: value.get('makeModel'),
                              child: Text(
                                '${value.get('makeModel')}',
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            debugPrint('makeModel selected: $value');
                            setState(
                              () {
                                // Selected value will be stored
                                carMakeModel = value;
                                // Default dropdown value won't be displayed anymore
                                setDefaultMakeModel = false;
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  : Container(
                      child: Text('carMake null carMake: $carMake makeModel: $carMakeModel'),
                    ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me out to make dropdown list according to my firestore data? Because your example works perfectly itself but with my data doesn't work. Can you show me  the exact one to get data from firestore map array list to dropdown list.